# Help Visual Basic mixing characters

Tags: vb.net, arrays, for-loop, character

I'm making an application that will change position of two characters in Word.

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

Sub Main()


    Dim str As String = File.ReadAllText("File.txt")
    Dim str2 As String() = Split(str, " ")
    For i As Integer = 0 To str2.Length - 1
        Dim arr As Char() = CType(str2(i), Char())

        For ia As Integer = 0 To arr.Length() - 1 Step 2
            Dim pa As String
            pa = arr(ia + 1)
            arr(ia + 1) = arr(ia)
            arr(ia) = pa
        Next ia
        For ib As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
            Console.Write(arr(ib))
            File.WriteAllText("File2.txt", arr(ib))
        Next ib
        File.WriteAllText("File2.txt", " ")
        Console.Write(" ")

    Next i
    Console.Read()

End Sub

End Module
```

For example:

```
Input: ab
Output: ba
Input: asdasd asdasd
Output: saadds saadds
```

Program works good, it is mixing characters good, but it doesn't write text to the file. It will write text in console, but not in file.

Note: Program is working only with words that are divisible by 2, but it's not a problem.
Also, it does not return any error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overwriting the file that you have already written with a single space (`" "`) each time round.

You should only open the file once, and append to it using a stream writer:

```
Using output = File.CreateText("file2.txt")
    ' Put the for loop here.    
End Using
```

There are some other things wrong with your code. Firstly, use `For Each` instead of `For`, this makes your code much more simple and readable. Secondly, try to avoid `For` loops altogether where possible. For instance, instead of iterating over the characters to output them one at a time, just create a new string from the char array, and write that:

```
Dim shuffledWord As New String(arr)
output.Write(shuffledWord)
```

Some of your types are plain wrong, i.e. you are using `String` in places instead of `Char`. You should **always** use `Option Strict On`. Then the compiler will not tolerate such code.

You should also prefer to use framework methods over VB-specific methods. This makes it easier to understand for C# programmers, and also makes it easier to translate and change (that is, use the `Split` method of strings instead of a free function, use `ToCharArray` instead of a cast to `Char()` …).

Finally, use meaningful variable names. `str`, `str2` and `arr` are particularly cryptic because they don’t tell the reader of the code *anything* of interest about the variables.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("File.txt")
    Dim words As String() = str.Split(" "c)
    Using output = File.CreateText("file2.txt")
        For Each word In words
            dim wordChars = word.ToCharArray()

            For i As Integer = 0 To wordChars.Length - 1 Step 2
                Dim tmp As Char = wordChars(i + 1)
                wordChars(i + 1) = wordChars(i)
                arr(i) = tmp
            Next

            Dim shuffledWord As New String(wordChars)
            output.Write(shuffledWord + " ")
            Console.Write(huffledWord + " ")
        Next
    End Using
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Comment: I have used output.Write() method but it still does not works. And I have tryed to use StreamWriter but it does not works too.

Comment: @FrewCen Have you had a look at the code I added? If that doesn’t work please update your question with more details. Unfortunately, I cannot test the code myself, I don’t have a working VB compiler installed.